# Can a Session Bean implement additional interface in addition to SB Interface?

Tags: java, interface, ejb, stateless-session-bean

I have a Session Bean like this:

```
@Stateless
@Local(MySessionBeanInterface.class)
public class MySessionBean implements MySessionBeanInterface {

}
```

I wanted to know if its okay to implement another interface as well. For instance, I have interface called, `MyXYXInterface`. I want the above bean to implement this as well.

```
@Stateless
@Local(MySessionBeanInterface.class)
public class MySessionBean implements MySessionBeanInterface, MyXYZInterface {

}
```

So, in the context of EJB's / Session Beans, is it a bad thing? does it interfere with treatment of EJBs in the container?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.  I do that all the time.

Comment: Yes it can. Next time at least try it before posting the question.

Comment: From programming perspective, it IS possible. But my question is if it interferes with any EJB related treatments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problems with implementing additional interfaces in addition to EJB so long as you use `@Local` explicitly (either on the EJB or on one of the interfaces on the implements clause).  If you don't use `@Local`, then the EJB container will "infer" the local interface, and if you add additional interfaces to the implements clause, that will cause problems.